# QGIS Refactor Fields unwanted behavior

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

QGIS Refactor Fields tool for altering attribute tables states:

> This algorithm allows editing the structure of the attributes table of
> a vector layer. Fields can be modified in their type and name, using a
> fields mapping.

Fields can also be added and deleted. However, output also alters the  length of all fields to 255. Is this expected behavior? Can original field lengths be retained?

Comment: Are you saving the output as a shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

There are options to have Length and Precision changed, but this is set to 0 by default. (Which I believe for a text field will end up being 255).

so in answer to your question - can the original field lengths be retained? Yes, but you will need to manually set them.

My suggestion is to use a template that you import and apply.