# Lines To Polygons and Polygonize attribute table problem

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, polygonize

On my systems, QGIS 2.18 64-bit, Windows 10, attribute tables produced by the `Lines To Polygons` tool and `Polygonize` tool differ from the table of the source layer.

The source table has two fields:

`ID--type Integer64, length 18`;

`PARCEL--type String, length 32`.

All fields in the output table are type `string, length 255`.

Is there some setting or step I am missing to produce output tables that have the same field type and length as the source table?

The `Lines to Polygons` tool states: "*The attribute table of the output layer is the same as the one of the input line layer.*"

I have tested on several other shapefiles.

Also, I get similar results with the `Refactor Fields` tool, i.e., all output table features are type `string, length 255`, which I addressed in this thread [QGIS Refactor Fields unwanted behavior](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254830/qgis-refactor-fields-unwanted-behavior).

**Update 10/8/17**
Appears to be bug in OGIS 2.18. Upgraded to latest version 2.18.13 today and tested 'Lines to Polygons' tool with same problem results.

Then downloaded and installed QGIS 2.14.19 and ran same test. Results are as desired and expected: output layer attribute table is same as input layer.

**Update 10/10/17**
Today I filed Bug report #17266 https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17266.

Comment: I followed the bug report link and saw the problem was solved. Hence, I'm voting to close this question as (problem no longer can be reproduced) and off-topic because this is a bug report; as recommended in our GIS Meta post [What should we do with bug reports?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-should-we-do-with-bug-reports).

Comment: Using 3.10.2-A Coruña under Windows 7 this problem persists. The attribute table returns NULL or empty fields. I added a "text 255" column to no avail...it returns blanks. Issue 17266 does not appear to have been closed for the current version.